# Styling a quote in a PM message reply

Tags: messages

I need a bit of code help please.

I have a messaging module for PM's that is using the following code for outputting the message body when replying to a PM:

```
else if (isset($extra['replying']) || isset($extra['forwarding']))
    {
        $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single('message', 
'[quote author="'.$original_author.'" date="'.$original_date.'"]'
.$original_body.'[/quote]', $tagdata);
    }
```

What I would like to do is have the quote moved to the bottom of the message so that the cursor automatically appears above it in the textarea and also I'd like to style the quote a bit with some line breaks between the author, date and original_body.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer to this via the codeigniter stackexchange. Someone suggsted using PHP_EOL as a predefined constant.

```
$tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single
('message', '---- Original Message ---- '.PHP_EOL.' date: '. 
$original_date.PHP_EOL.$original_body.' ---', $tagdata);
```